# React native fetch request failed

Tags: android, react-native, request, fetch

I dont know what I changed, but the fetch request is not working anymore (only using Android). It worked before, tried to change it back, but couldnt get it to work.

I tried the links in this issue: [React native network request failed while fetching data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834474/react-native-network-request-failed-while-fetching-data)

Im using the correct IP address. (Took Ipconfig IPv4 Address for the URL) as I always did. Dev settings on android Debug server host & port for device is empty and device is connected through a USB cable. When I type in the IP address in the browser its showing the correct JSON data.

I tried to debug it with the Remote JS Debugging, but didnt found information why it failed. *had to add a space between 'http://' -> 'http ://' because Im not allowed to give alot of links* The error message said:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>   TypeError: Network request failed
>   TypeError: Network request failed
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (blob:http ://localhost:8081/a0fa7e28-6cd7-4abe-899c-cb0e0ec650a8:15827:18)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (blob:http ://localhost:8081/a0fa7e28-6cd7-4abe-899c-cb0e0ec650a8:17904:39)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (blob:http ://localhost:8081/a0fa7e28-6cd7-4abe-899c-cb0e0ec650a8:17659:20)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (blob:http ://localhost:8081/a0fa7e28-6cd7-4abe-899c-cb0e0ec650a8:17486:16)
>       at blob:http ://localhost:8081/a0fa7e28-6cd7-4abe-899c-cb0e0ec650a8:17596:47
>       at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (blob:http ://localhost:8081/a0fa7e28-6cd7-4abe-899c-cb0e0ec650a8:3482:37)
>       at MessageQueue.__callFunction (blob:http ://localhost:8081/a0fa7e28-6cd7-4abe-899c-cb0e0ec650a8:2388:44)
>       at blob:http ://localhost:8081/a0fa7e28-6cd7-4abe-899c-cb0e0ec650a8:2158:17
>       at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (blob:http ://localhost:8081/a0fa7e28-6cd7-4abe-899c-cb0e0ec650a8:2350:11)
>       at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http ://localhost:8081/a0fa7e28-6cd7-4abe-899c-cb0e0ec650a8:2157:14)

Code snippet of the page where i use the fetch request:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableHighlight,
    ListView,
    Image,
    List,
    FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import TurfLijst from './TurfPage';

var rowBackgroundColour = 'white';
var imageBackgroundColour = 'gray';
var nameBackgroundColour = '#ADD8E6'; // light blue
var borderRadius = 5;

class TurfGroupsOverview extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})

        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds,
            user: 'None',
        }
    }

    // fetch turflist data from the database.
    componentWillMount() {
        const URL = 'http://145.**.***.***:9455/group/';
        console.log("Before fetching");

        this.setState({loading: true});
        fetch(URL, {
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                console.log("after fetching, before saving");

                this.setState({
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(response),
                });
                console.log("after saving to this.state");
            }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("ERROR OCCURED: " + error);

            throw error;
        });
    }

    renderRow(group) {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('TurfPage', {
                    group: group,
                    members: group.members,
                    groupName: group.name
                });
            }
            }>
                <View style={[styles.boxContainer, styles.turfList]}>
                    <View style={styles.turfName}>
                        <Text>{group.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.turfPicture}>
                        <Image style={{width: "100%", height: "100%", borderRadius: borderRadius}}
                               source={({uri: group.picture})}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {console.log("Calling the render function")}
                {console.log("dataSource: " + this.state.dataSource.toString())}
                <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default TurfGroupsOverview;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',

    },

    boxContainer: {
        height: 100,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },

    turfList: {
        backgroundColor: rowBackgroundColour,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },

    turfListTwo: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },

    turfName: {
        backgroundColor: nameBackgroundColour,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 0.7,
        height: '80%',
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
    },

    turfPicture: {
        backgroundColor: imageBackgroundColour,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 0.2,
        height: '80%',
        maxWidth: 80,
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
    }
});
```

The data i try to fetch

```
[{"uuid":"68e706e1-2e47-43e6-b0b2-2cd91eba107b","name":"Group 1","picture":"http://www.israelgives.org/Pictures/AmutaPictures/5201_Large_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%98%204.jpg","members":[{"uuid":"76f64769-4afa-4216-ac9e-6251da40cf50","firstName":"Ivo","lastName":"Chen","email":"ivo@ivo.nl","imageLocation":"https://thesurrianlife.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/macaque-monkey-canon-dslr-self-portrait-234x300.jpg"},{"uuid":"4d18c8dc-42a0-42fe-9cfc-223af355daaf","firstName":"Martin","lastName":"van Keulen","email":"martin@martin.nl","imageLocation":"https://s.redditmedia.com/t5_93cn9/styles/profileIcon_gsz1rsc9tc401.jpg?fit=crop&crop=faces%2Centropy&arh=1.0&w=256&h=256&s=338416408f027bd8ca437459e99dd146"}],"productList":[{"uuid":"7002648c-fbe4-40b8-9ff7-7aec01cddea1","price":1.0,"amountInStock":10,"imageLocation":null,"nameProcuct":"Hertog Jan","inStock":true},{"uuid":"be6a6b61-3726-401e-8a9c-7883e16338f2","price":1.5,"amountInStock":43,"imageLocation":null,"nameProcuct":"Heineken","inStock":true}]},{"uuid":"69b1a310-2c6d-4ed0-bb51-7cead98382fd","name":"Group 2","picture":"http://www.israelgives.org/Pictures/AmutaPictures/5201_Large_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%98%204.jpg","members":[{"uuid":"feb830b4-14a6-4c40-afc9-2339726b0347","firstName":"Ivo","lastName":"Chen","email":"ivo@ivo.nl","imageLocation":"https://thesurrianlife.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/macaque-monkey-canon-dslr-self-portrait-234x300.jpg"},{"uuid":"e9b43044-6a13-473a-8259-b795215fdbcb","firstName":"Martin","lastName":"van Keulen","email":"martin@martin.nl","imageLocation":"https://s.redditmedia.com/t5_93cn9/styles/profileIcon_gsz1rsc9tc401.jpg?fit=crop&crop=faces%2Centropy&arh=1.0&w=256&h=256&s=338416408f027bd8ca437459e99dd146"}],"productList":[{"uuid":"4e45e620-a18a-4602-93d3-c3a5196a2643","price":1.0,"amountInStock":10,"imageLocation":null,"nameProcuct":"Hertog Jan","inStock":true},{"uuid":"47600a90-7614-422e-a87c-ba0d3c97bb91","price":1.5,"amountInStock":43,"imageLocation":null,"nameProcuct":"Heineken","inStock":true}]},{"uuid":"231a502a-c05f-494e-880e-bfd4b3b2f281","name":"Group 3","picture":"http://ivochen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Background_No_User.png","members":[{"uuid":"c72348fe-d838-44d4-96b2-4b20d7f68e64","firstName":"Ivo","lastName":"Chen","email":"ivo@ivo.nl","imageLocation":"https://thesurrianlife.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/macaque-monkey-canon-dslr-self-portrait-234x300.jpg"},{"uuid":"c9cf7771-a1f5-41aa-b2d7-c2e887dce2fd","firstName":"Martin","lastName":"van Keulen","email":"martin@martin.nl","imageLocation":"https://s.redditmedia.com/t5_93cn9/styles/profileIcon_gsz1rsc9tc401.jpg?fit=crop&crop=faces%2Centropy&arh=1.0&w=256&h=256&s=338416408f027bd8ca437459e99dd146"}],"productList":[{"uuid":"d206ebc9-2142-4474-9e46-f2aa133684b7","price":1.0,"amountInStock":10,"imageLocation":null,"nameProcuct":"Hertog Jan","inStock":true},{"uuid":"17e329f9-8981-41dc-b474-764bdc3ef871","price":1.5,"amountInStock":43,"imageLocation":null,"nameProcuct":"Heineken","inStock":true}]},{"uuid":"1f39a0c3-8ff2-4fe4-9e81-0480e4c51001","name":"Heren residentie Fjirma Bretels","picture":"http://ivochen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Background_No_User.png","members":[{"uuid":"95f61185-2536-4204-894c-ae5e49811312","firstName":"Ivo","lastName":"Chen","email":"ivo@ivo.nl","imageLocation":"https://thesurrianlife.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/macaque-monkey-canon-dslr-self-portrait-234x300.jpg"},{"uuid":"b396a5cb-3f30-4f27-82f3-bc102cda38ba","firstName":"Martin","lastName":"van Keulen","email":"martin@martin.nl","imageLocation":"https://s.redditmedia.com/t5_93cn9/styles/profileIcon_gsz1rsc9tc401.jpg?fit=crop&crop=faces%2Centropy&arh=1.0&w=256&h=256&s=338416408f027bd8ca437459e99dd146"}],"productList":[{"uuid":"4746ef90-9c36-45fd-87c1-a2924aa0c792","price":1.0,"amountInStock":10,"imageLocation":null,"nameProcuct":"Hertog Jan","inStock":true},{"uuid":"4059ff8b-09ed-4103-92f1-2590170d7ced","price":1.5,"amountInStock":43,"imageLocation":null,"nameProcuct":"Heineken","inStock":true}]}]
```

[Image for a better view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXQAZ.png)

Comment: Oke I was not paying attention I was not on the same WIFI. Didnt had to change any code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke quit stupid from my side. I was not connected with the same WIFI...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this type of problems usually when

1. My internet didn't work.
2. I am not on the same network where my localhost is deployed.
3. My emulator or device is in flight mode.